# Getting issue while attaching file in cucumber jvm report apart from screenshot

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

On Failure screenshots is getting captured successfully, but for some steps I need to attach file (text/log/excel) in cucumber-JVM report. But I am getting scenario null.

**DemoDef.java**

```
TestContext textContext;
public DemoDef(TestContext textContext){
   textContext = textContext
}

@Given("Is file downloaded successfully")
public void userIsOnLoginScreen() {
    SoftAssertions.assertSoftly(softAssertions -> softAssertions.assertThat(testContext.pageObjectManager().getDemo().isFileDownloaded()).as("File Not Downloaded").isTrue());
     testContext.getScenario().attach("FileName", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", "Downloaded FileName");
}
```

**AssetHook.java**

```
public AssertHook(TestContext context) {
        testContext = context;
    }
    
    @Before
    public void beforeScenario(Scenario scenario) {
        testContext.setScenario(scenario); //Here setting the scenrio
    }
    
    @AfterStep
    public void takeScreenShotsOnStepFailure(Scenario scenario) {
        switch (scenario.getStatus()) {
            case SKIPPED, PENDING, UNDEFINED, AMBIGUOUS, FAILED, UNUSED -> {
                try {
                    byte[] screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot) testContext.getAppiumDriver()).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
                    scenario.attach(new ImageUtilities().resizeBytesImage(screenshot), "image/png", CucumberListener.stepName);
                } catch (Exception exception) {
                    utils.log().info(exception.getCause().toString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**TestContext.java** using reference from [here](https://www.toolsqa.com/rest-assured/share-scenario-context/)

```
@Getter @Setter
    AppiumDriver appiumDriver;

    @Getter
    @Accessors(fluent = true)
    ScenarioContext scenarioContext;

    @Getter
    @Accessors(fluent = true)
    PageObjectManager pageObjectManager;

    @Getter @Setter
    Scenario scenario;

    @Getter
    private final ConfigurationProperties configurationProperties = ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration();

    public TestContext() {
        setAppiumDriver(GenericDriverFactory.getMobileDriverManager().getDriver());
        scenarioContext = new ScenarioContext();
        pageObjectManager = new PageObjectManager();
    }
```

Is there any other ways to achieve the same?

Comment: Show us the exception

Comment: @AlexeyR. This is the exception
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "io.cucumber.java.Scenario.attach(String, String, String)" because the return value of "utilities.cucumber.context.TestContext.getScenario()" is null
at stepDefinitions.screens.login.TestLogin.userIsOnLoginScreen(TestLogin.java:113)
at ✽.User is on login screen(classpath:features/STPLAndExpressCash.feature:6)

Comment: Don't add context in commands. And also add your feature file please.